# CSS. Three columns, the outer two variable width but wrapping their content, the middle expanding to fill the available horizontal space

Tags: css, html-table, flexbox, css-grid

I have a straightforward bit of html as follows:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col--outer col--left">
    Variable content here but the div should fit snuggly round it
  </div>
  <div class="col col--middle">
    <!-- This div should fill the space left on the row -->
  </div>
  <div class="col col--outer col--right">
    Variable content here but the div should fit snuggly round it
  </div>
</div>
```

It's been designed so the left and right column contain an image which will vary in size with the column containing it fitting it exactly.

The middle column needs to expand to fit the space left on the row.

If the outer columns were a fixed dimension it would make things much easier but unfortunately they are not.

Any ideas on how to tackle this?

User @SuperDJ requested I show the CSS also, so here it is:

```
.row {}
.row .col--outer {}
.row .col--middle {}
```

Comment: You tagged the question as CSS so can you please add your CSS

Comment: @SuperDJ I had no idea how to achieve the required result hence the lack of CSS, I have, however, now posted the barebones CSS so that your request was satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.row{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row ;
    width: 100%
}

.col--left,.col--right{
    flex-basis: auto;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

.col--middle{
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
}
```

`flex-basis:auto;` for the left and right element so it takes the exact width he needs to be displayed. `flex-grow: 0;` and `flex-shrink: 0` to forbid them to resize.

`flex-grow: 1` and `flex-shrink: 1` to the middle element so it takes all the remaining space.

Comment: This is great and has helped me to understand flex. It both, achieves the desired result and is widely supported. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The following example will give the outer columns all the space while the middle will just fill what is left

```css
.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
  /* 
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); to make them equal width */
  width: 100%;
}

.col--left {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.col--middle {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.col--right {
  grid-column: 3;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 200px; /* Could also be 100% */
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col--outer col--left">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/11/29/21/19/hamburg-3846525_960_720.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="col col--middle">
    <!-- This div should fill the space left on the row -->
    middle
    there is so much text in here
  </div>
  <div class="col col--outer col--right">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/11/29/21/19/hamburg-3846525_960_720.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is incredibly useful and gives me some insight into using Grid. I'm grateful for the time you took writing it. It certainly achieves the desired result. My concern is support.

Comment: First place I checked, I tested both your Grid based solution and @joffrey-schmitz's flex solution. Both insightful and useful but flex was more widely supported.